# Discord bot hosted on heroku, doesn't run

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord, discord.py

So I made a discord bot and I hosted it on heroku using github. I added some more functions, edited the code on github and finally deployed the bot again. And now the bot won't run.
Just exits process with `Process exited with status code 0`, not running the bot.

I tried running it with a different bot token and *it works*.

Here is the output when I use a different bot token.

```
2020-10-29T09:45:32.309985+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-29T09:45:37.359078+00:00 app[worker.1]: Running as another music bot
2020-10-29T09:45:37.431057+00:00 app[worker.1]: Reddit Cog Loaded
2020-10-29T09:45:37.434029+00:00 app[worker.1]: Help Cog Loaded
2020-10-29T09:45:37.445268+00:00 app[worker.1]: Booru Cog Loaded
2020-10-29T09:45:38.848149+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

And here is the output when I use the original bot token. (Tried regenerating the token too, but no, nothing.)

```
2020-10-29T10:14:46.286805+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-29T10:14:52.890101+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

The problem is not that the code doesn't work, but that *it works with a different bot's token*.
Meaning there are no errors in the code, *I guess?*
I know the status 0 means no errors but as you can see the bot doesn't even start to print those lines...

Not knowing what to do, here I am...

Comment: Your bot may be in no guilds. Your bot may not have [privileged intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents). It can be anything.

Comment: @TinNguyen my bot already is in 64 guilds and it doesn't really needs to track members aside from counting total guild members with `guild.member_count`.  _so I added the member intent if needed_ but still no. Anything else which could be an obvious problem?

Comment: You will have to debug your code and add more log messages and see which code isn't reached.

Comment: @Tin Nguyen Sorry for late reply sire, but as I said I tried running another bot and it worked so I thinks it's something on heroku's side?... And after leaving it for a while, it was up again.. I dunno what's up so will leave it as it is ig? At least it's up now... Much thanks for the replies sire